# Polynomial rings and quotients

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $F$ be a field, $x$ an indeterminate in $F$, and $f(x)\in F[x]$ a polynomial with degree n. If the "Overline" denotes the canonical homomorphism from $F[x]\rightarrow F[x]/<f(x)>$, then, how can I show 2. without using 1.? Can 2. be shown without using Division algorithm?

1. For every polynomial $g(x)\in F[x]$ there exists a polynomial $g_0(x)$ of degree less than n such that $\overline{g(x)}=\overline{g_0(x)}$.
2. The elements $\overline{1},\overline{x},...,\overline{x^{n-1}}$ form a basis for the vector space $F[x]/<f(x)>$.

The first proposition seems just like a corollary for division algorithm, the second one seems very disconnected and interesting, and it can be shown using 1. I wonder if it can be shown without using 1. or division algorithm. 
Furthermore, can 1. be shown from 2., without supposing division algorithm?

Could these propositions be equivalent?
What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint for 2 without 1.
$\overline{f (x)}=\overline{0}$, then $\overline{x}^n=a_{n-1}\overline{x}^{n-1}+\cdots+ a_1\overline{x}+a_0$  (i). Now multipling this relation by $\overline{x}$. We get $\overline{x}^{n+1}=a_{n-1}\overline{x}^n +\cdots+ a_1\overline{x}^2+a_0\overline{x}$. Using (i), we have $\overline{x}^{n+1}=b_{n-1}\overline{x}^{n-1}+\cdots+ b_1\overline{x}+b_0$ (where $b_0=a_0$). Etc, etc... thus for all $k$, $\overline{x}^{n+k}=r_{n-1}\overline{x}^{n-1}+\cdots+ r_1\overline{x}+r_0$. That is, $\{\overline{x}^{n-1},\cdots, \overline{x},\overline {1}\}$ generates. The independence is obvious.
Sorry for my english.